# time zone being removed from query result after putting into a generic sobject

Tags: apex, soql, custom-object, class

Note i can provide full code examples for running , but for brevity i am including snippets at this time

i have a query that i am dynamically retrieving all fields and placing them in an object to later serialize

```
        set<Id> recordIds = objIDMap.get(objectName);
        String objQuery = 'SELECT '+ String.join( fields, ',' ) + ' FROM ' + res.getName() +    ' WHERE ' + ' id IN:recordIds';
        system.debug('objQuery: '+objQuery);
        recordsMap.put(objectName, new map<Id, SObject>(Database.query(objQuery)));
       SObject record = recordsMap.get(objectName).get(recordId);
       List<SObject> records = new list<Sobject>{record};
       system.debug('records:'+records);
```

when the **records** variable is being assigned, the createddate equals this in the log

```
 {...,"CreatedDate":"2020-11-11T19:54:54.000Z","CreatedById":"00536000002oIZ5AAM", ...}
```

but when the system debug **records** is viewed the createddate equals this, it looks like the time zones have been stripped

```
 CreatedDate=2020-11-11 19:54:54, CreatedById=00536000002oIZ5AAM,
```

and later in the program when i write the field to the json object the time zone stays off the value

is this due to being in a generic sObject? i want to retain all fields as the values queried from the system

Answer (score 0):

Debug logs always show date/time values in UTC. Similarly serializing Date/time values to JSON results in UTC values. As such there's little need to retain the Zulu "timezone" identifier.